# CheckedTextView not changing drawable

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, listactivity, checkedtextview

I want the user to be able to select multiple apps from a list. I'm using a custom layout for a list of installed apps with their icons using Drawables and CheckedTextViews. I created a class extended from ArrayAdapter to get the icons.

The main problem is when I tap on a app in the list the CheckedTextView doesn't change it's drawable, it does however set the CheckedTextView as checked so functionality still works but it's not very useful if you can't see which ones are checked. I'm still new to Android but I think the problem is in my array adapter.

ListActivity:

```
public class FilterListActivity extends ListActivity {
private AppArrayAdapter adapt;
private ArrayList<String> oldChecked =new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayMap<String, ApplicationInfo> availableApps;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.filter_list);

    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    availableApps=getAvailableApps();

    ArrayList<String> appArray=new ArrayList<String>(availableApps.keySet());
    Collections.sort(appArray);
    adapt = new AppArrayAdapter( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, appArray);
    setListAdapter(adapt);
    try{
        //check for previous settings
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(openFileInput("priorityList.txt"));
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(buf).useDelimiter(",|\\n");
        while (scan.hasNext()){
            String appLabel = scan.next();
            String packageName = scan.next();
            int pos = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
            oldChecked.add(appLabel);
            //set item as checked
            int i = adapt.getPosition(appLabel);
            if (i>=0){
                CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)adapt.getView(i, getCurrentFocus(), getListView()).findViewById(R.id.app_names);
                if (textView.getText().toString().equals(appLabel)){
                    this.getListView().setItemChecked(i, true);
                    textView.setChecked(true);


                }
            }
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        //do nothing, list must be created
    }
    adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick( ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)v.findViewById(R.id.app_names);

    textView.toggle();
    adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".AppView" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:contentDescription="icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/app_names"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Array Adapter:

```
package edit.rit.ce.whud;

import java.util.List;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AppArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final List<String> objects;
private ArrayMap<String, ApplicationInfo> availableApps;

public AppArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects)
{
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    //this.values = values;
    this.objects=objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final PackageManager pm = this.getContext().getPackageManager();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.appview, parent, false);
    CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.app_names);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(objects.get(position));

    // Change icon based on name
    String applabel = objects.get(position);
    availableApps=getAvailableApps();

    Drawable draw= pm.getApplicationIcon(availableApps.get(applabel));
    imageView.setImageDrawable(draw);

    return rowView;

}



private ArrayMap<String, ApplicationInfo> getAvailableApps(){
    ArrayMap<String, ApplicationInfo> availableApps= new ArrayMap<String, ApplicationInfo>();
    final PackageManager pm = this.getContext().getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    for(ApplicationInfo app:  apps){
        if (app.enabled && (app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_TEST_ONLY)==0){
            availableApps.put((String)pm.getApplicationLabel(app), app);
        }
    }
    return availableApps;

}
```

}